# $(E\oplus F)/(E_1 \oplus F_1)$ and $E/E_1 \oplus F/F_1$ are isomorphics

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vector spaces $E$ and $F$,

show that  $(E\oplus F)/(E_1 \oplus F_1)$ and $E/E_1 \oplus F/F_1$ are isomorphics

This is my idea:

consider subspaces $E_{1}\subset E$, $F_1\subset F$ and the canonical projections

$$\pi_{E}: E \to E_1 $$ $$\pi_{F}: F \to F_1$$.

define a mapping

$\phi(x,y): E \oplus F \to E/E_1 \oplus F/F_1$

by:

$\phi(x,y)=(\pi_E(x),\pi_F(y))$

I think that this function can induce the given isomorphism but I cannot find how to relate it to another function relate it to another function to be able to test the ismorphism. Can you help me?

Comment: what I need to do is prove that $\phi$ induces an isomorphism

Comment: $\phi$ is surjective and its kernel is $E_1\oplus F_1$. Use the first isomorphism theorem for vector spaces.